# POST /wp-json/wp/v2/posts HTTP/1.1" 404

Tags: python, wordpress, flask, oauth-2.0

I get 404 error

```
# WordPress OAuth 2.0 configuration
wordpress = oauth.remote_app(
    'wordpress',
    consumer_key=WP_CLIENT_ID,       # Replace with your WordPress client ID
    consumer_secret=WP_CLIENT_SECRAT, # Replace with your WordPress client secret
    base_url='https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url='https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token',
    authorize_url='https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize',
    request_token_params={'scope': 'auth-publish'}
)

    @wordpress.tokengetter
    def get_wordpress_oauth_token():
           return session.get('wordpress_token')
               ....
       session['wordpress_token'] = (response['access_token'], '')
               ....

    @app.route('/wordpress/<int:id>', methods=['POST'])
    def wp_post(id):
     wordpress_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
     access_token = get_wordpress_oauth_token()
     print(access_token[0])
     headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token[0]}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
     }
     # Blog post data
     post_data = {
      'title': 'My New Blog Post',
      'content': 'This is the content of my blog post.',
      'status': 'publish'
      }
      response = requests.post(wordpress_url, json=post_data, headers=headers)
      if response.status_code == 201:
          return jsonify({"message": "Successfully"}), 200
      else:
          return jsonify({"message": "Post not posted"}), 404
```

On post request post should publish on WordPress.

I don't what is problem is there any solution for that. It should me post on WordPress.

Comment: What is the "f" before Bearer header?

Comment: @giacomoto it is f-string

Comment: You are not _getting_ a 404, you are _responding_ with a 404. And you do that, when `response.status_code` of that API call is _not_ 201. So start by checking what response you actually got. Also check what the response body might have contained.

Comment: @CBroe I think wordpress is not giving me permission to upload post in request method or there is access token is not working. Idk. Can you suggest me to solve this problem

Comment: I already told you what you should check first of all.